# My GPU is not getting listed when I check for GPU using tensorflow?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, gpu

when i run this on anaconda jupyter notebook

import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices()

the output is:

[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]

why is python not detecting my gpu?

my specs CPU - Ryzen 7 5600H
GPU - NVIDIA RTX 3050
RAM - 16gb

When i run nvidia smi it shows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUyaS.png)

but does not show gpu on tf.config.list_physical_devices()
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the tags that you are using Windows.
The support for GPUs on Native Windows changed with TensorFlow 2.11.

The [install guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) states the following:

> Caution: TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to install [TensorFlow in WSL2](https://tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2), or install tensorflow-cpu and, optionally, try the [TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml-plugin#tensorflow-directml-plugin-)